# Revert changes from stream

Tags: visual-studio-2013, perforce

I have two streams : 
-dev - it is used by all developers and whole changes were marged to this stream
-netmajor - it is my own private stream

When I have few changes I Submit them to my private depot and then I see on Dashboard information "Copy to dev (x changes)"

When I Submit this changes from my stream to Changelist on dev depot I see that some files were submit unnecessary, so I revert them. After this I see on my private depot Dashboard information "Copy to dev".

Were files reverted to private depot? 
Why I can not see them on Pending tab?  How can I revert them from private depot like these changes never exist?
When I Submit changes to Depot, they cannot be removed back to workspace?

Answer (score 1):

Roll back the changes in your private stream -- you can pick a point in time (e.g. a changelist) you want to roll everything back to, or you can pick individual changelists that you want to back out while leaving other (possibly later) changelists intact.  This is done with either the "roll back" or "back out" command in P4V, or by "p4 sync" and "p4 edit" at the command line.

There's an in-depth video tutorial here: http://www.perforce.com/resources/tutorials/rolling-back-backing-out-changes